# What is this fruit?

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees, fruit

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

There is a hairy hard shell (looking like a small kiwi), which naturally breaks, and under it there is brain-shaped red sweet flesh, half-covering the smooth black seed.

Picture taken in the Mediterranean coast of Israel in August

Comment: Kinf of Morus : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morus_(plant)

Comment: I think this tree is not native to the Mediterranean (cause I've never seen it). Was it located in a garden? Can you ask the owner of the house?

Comment: @RHA I have seen it mostly in public places, along roads, in a hopital, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might it be [Alectryon tomentosus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alectryon_tomentosus)?

To me, the fruit looks the same and also the leaves have the same look. [image: Alectryon fruit]

It is an Australian tree whose common name is "wooly rambutan" and is used as a [street tree](https://emahotrees.com.au/products/alectryon-tomentosus-woolly-rambutan) as you observed. I did not find instances of this tree in Israel, though.

Answer (score -7):

Kind of Morus, I have seen this in Morocco and it is delicious : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morus_(plant)

Comment: No. Morus has many small seeds, this one has one big seed. Morus has no shell around the fruit.

Comment: @Anixx I didn't say it is Morus, I said kind of Morus, which means Morus Family